# .map not a function after triggering a setState with useState hooks

Tags: javascript, hook

The component will render for first time but when I trigger the handleControls function, error says that ingredients.map is not a function, it is basically saying that my ingredients state becomes undefined after I triggered the handleControl function. I am scratch my head over this issue for a while now, no idea how to fix it, please give a brother a hand!!! Thank you in advance!!!

```js
//useState
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([{
  id: 1,
  name: 'flour',
  calories: '1520 / 362',
  protein: 7.9,
  fat: 6.6,
  fiber: 3.3,
  carbs: 3.3,
  cholersterol: 0.2,
  vitaminc: 0.2,
  controls: false
}])
```

function to change the control's value

```js
function handleControl(e, index) {
  let value = e.target.value
  setIngredients(state => {
    state.ingredents[index].controls = !value
    return (
      // { ...prevIngredient, controls: !prevIngredient.controls}
      { ...state }
    )
  })
}
```

component to render

```html
<TableBody>
  {ingredients && ingredients.map((ingredient,index) => (
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
      {ingredient.id}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.name}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.calories}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.protein}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.fiber}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.fat}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.carbs}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.cholesterol}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{ingredient.vitaminc}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">
      { // ingredient.controls // ? //
       <>
        // <button className={ingredient.id}>Save</button> // <button className={ingredient.id}>Cancel</button> //
        </> // :
        <>
          <button onClick={ (e)=>{handleControl(e,index)}} value={ingredient.controls} className={ingredient.id}>Edit</button>
          <button className={ingredient.id}>Delete</button>
        </> 
       }
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
  )) }
</TableBody>
```

Comment: You set an `{}` instead of `[]` in `setIngredients`. Problem is [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can only be called on arrays.

Comment: I enclosed the object with [] tags, so it should register as an array of objects

Comment: Your state starts out as an array, but then when you call `setIngredients`, you're doing this: `useIngredients(state => { })` and within that using `state.ingredents`. It should just be `state` (which I would call `ingredients`), e.g. `setIngredients(ingredients => { })` and then return another array. The state item is an array, not an object, in this case.

Comment: like this? setIngredients( ingredients => {
                   ingredents[index].controls = !value
              return ( {...ingredients} ) })

Comment: still shooting out .map not a function error

Comment: Ingredients is an array; why do you keep destructuring it inside an object?

Comment: because i am trying to change the controls property of that object to achieve conditional rendering

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the list to an Object by this line

```js
 setIngredients(state => {
    state.ingredents[index].controls = !value
    return (
      // { ...prevIngredient, controls: !prevIngredient.controls}
      { ...state }
    )
  })
```

You should just return the New State as an array, as below:

```js
 setIngredients(state => {
    state[index].controls = !value
    return state
  })
```

Comment: now its returning cant read property '0' of undefined

Comment: also how would i preserve the other properties of the object after setIngredients?